# Как правильно получить элементы DOM в React

Tags: reactjs

Если получить их так где они после сборки живут в глобальной области видимости или только в окружении компонента

```
let nodes = null

export const Comp = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        nodes = document.querySelectorAll('anyWrapper a')    
    }, []);

    // сделать что то с этими нодами
    return <></>;
}
```

или можно для этого использовать useState например так

```
export const Comp = () => {
    const [nodes, setNodes] = useState(null)
        useEffect(() => {
            setNodes(document.querySelectorAll('anyWrapper a'))
        }, []);

    // сделать что то с этими нодами
    return <></>;
}
```

или по другому

Comment: По идее через `ref`. Если, конечно, они внутри компонена.

Comment: @Qwertiy не привязывать же ref ко всем тегам a ну или к родителю но тогда тоже через querySelectorAll нужно будет всех взять

Comment: Вероятно ты что-то делаешь не так, раз тебе нужен ref на всех тегах.

Comment: @Qwertiy возможно ты прав это был мой первый проект на react уже не помню зачем мне нужны было прямое обрашение к дом но все же неужели react разрабы не предусмотрели вот такой вариант ... как ты правильно заметил они могут быть вне компонента не прокидивать же ref через всю возможную иирархию